# Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

TL;DR: I have a Spring MVC *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)* application that works on Tomcat 9. The same application on Tomcat 10 gives a 404 error for web request mappings.

**The Problem**

When deploying a Spring MVC 5 *Hello, World!* application to Tomcat 10, the application gives a 404 error for web request mappings. The same *Hello, World!* application works on Tomcat 9. It displays the *Hello, World!* message on Tomcat 9.

**What I Expected**

I expected the application to display the *Hello, World!* message on Tomcat 10.

**Environment**

- MS Windows 10
- Tomcat 10.0.2
- Spring MVC 5.3.3

**Research I Performed**

I researched in the Spring Reference Manual, Section on Web Servlet. I also tested Spring MVC Tutorials online. These tutorials worked on Tomcat 9. However, the same tutorials failed on Tomcat 10. I also performed Google search on Tomcat 10. I saw references to Jakarta EE, but I am not sure if this is the source of the issue. Java EE 8 and Jakarta EE 8 are backwards compatible.

**How to Reproduce**

I created a very basic *Hello, World!* project to test this out. Here is the code that I'm using for the project.

#### File *pom.xml*

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### File *ProjectInitializer.java*

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ProjectInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { PureJavaConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### File *PureJavaConfig.java*

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class PureJavaConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

#### File *TutorialController.java*

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class TutorialController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

#### File *home.jsp*

```html
<html>
    <body>Hello, World! of Spring! <%= java.time.LocalDateTime.now() %></body>
</html>
```

This project runs okay on Tomcat 9. It displays the *Hello, World!* message. However, when I run on Tomcat 10, I get a 404 error message.

Comment: With no other details, it will be hard for anyone to help. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.  Your error message implies a large chunk of the Servlet implementation is missing, so it's likely an installation error or configuration error.

Comment: @JimGarrison - thank you sir for reference on how to ask question. I am sorry i did not follow the correct procedures. I have updated my question with more details, source code and expected outcome.

Comment: since he has added all details, we should revert our down vote

Answer (score 49, accepted):

*TL;DR: Spring MVC 5 does not run on Tomcat 10 because of the package renaming from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.*

After further research, I was able to find the answer to my question. Spring MVC 5 does *not* work on Tomcat 10. This is because Tomcat 10 is based on Jakarta EE 9 where package names for APIs have changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.

Tomcat 10 mentioned this on the [download webpage](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi):

> Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the
> move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to
> the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs
> has changed from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. This will almost certainly
> require code changes to enable applications to migrate from Tomcat 9
> and earlier to Tomcat 10 and later.

For Spring MVC 5, the Spring MVC [DispatcherServlet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.3/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java) has a dependency on the `javax.servlet.*` package namespace. This is using the Java EE 8 `javax` package naming. Since Tomcat 10 is based on Jakarta EE 9, the packages for `javax` naming are not supported. This explains why Spring MVC 5 does not work on Tomcat 10.

There are GitHub issues filed against the Spring Framework regarding this:

*[Spring core 5 is not starting on Tomcat 10](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25276)*

*[Support for Jakarta EE 9 (annotations and interfaces in jakarta.* namespace)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25354)*

In my case, instead of migrating to Tomcat 10, I will stay on Tomcat 9 until the Spring framework is upgraded to Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: In the second paragraph wrote `Spring MVC 5 does currently work on Tomcat 10`. So does it work or does it not?

Comment: @izogfif: oh that was a typo. it does not work.
I added the *not*. I made the edits to my answer: _Spring MVC 5 does *not* work on Tomcat 10._

Comment: How about spring MVC 6.0.9. I have also the same problem with the latest available versions. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that some of the issues with javax.servlet->jakarta.servlet mentioned in other answers can be worked around deploying in webapps-javaee instead of webapps. It has worked quite well for me.

This will process the war through a migration tool that will modify the files, including class files, changing those packages.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem as mentioned from @knelson is right. And painfull! :-/

For us it was not just Spring (6.0.10), it was just a lot of releated dependencies, Hibernate/JPA (6.2.2.Final), JAXB, Servlets API (6), Maven Plugins und so on.

I will suggest you to watch really nice video, i was watching of the IntelliJ colleages (Dalia Abo Sheasha):

https://youtu.be/mukr2Q_zBm4

There are some tipps how these task/migration could be less painful with the help of IntelliJ and maven dependencies analysis.

After that i was getting 404 Http Status calling a servlet. Issue was the flag metadata-complete from web.xml. I copied from the example that come with Tomcat   and this was not setting right. For me it was needed metadata-complete="false" in the web.xml but from example it was true.