# Spring Boot WAR with External Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

A well-worn topic, but the second day there is no result.

Made an extremely simple test case with Docker https://github.com/iormark/test-spring-boot

Help please, why it doesn't work, always 404
[image]

Comment: You are right, I forgot to explain the problem

Comment: Post Dockerfile and Docker command that you are using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat 10.0.4 doesn't load servlets (@WebServlet classes) with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66806582/tomcat-10-0-4-doesnt-load-servlets-webservlet-classes-with-404-error)

Comment: Another related question: [Deploying Spring MVC 5 on Tomcat 10 … deployment problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66217350/11748454)