# Desciption - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

HomeController page

```
package springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("This is home url");
        return "index";
    }
    
}
```

spring-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScehma-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.controller"></context:component-scan>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" name="viewResolver">
    
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    
    </beans>
```

web.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is home page</h1>
    <h1>Called by home controller</h1>
    <h1>url /home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring.mvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>springmvc</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

error

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found


Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.


Apache Tomcat/10.0.10
```

after running the project on server it shows http 404 error as shown above. I have tried other solutions given on stack overflow but none of them worked. I am following a playlist on youtube for learning spring mvc.

when I used tomcat 8.5 it show error and in the console it is printing

```
Sep 06, 2021 10:16:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:415)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:626)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
```

Catalina.properties

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

#
# List of comma-separated packages that start with or equal this string
# will cause a security exception to be thrown when
# passed to checkPackageAccess unless the
# corresponding RuntimePermission ("accessClassInPackage."+package) has
# been granted.
package.access=sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.tomcat.
#
# List of comma-separated packages that start with or equal this string
# will cause a security exception to be thrown when
# passed to checkPackageDefinition unless the
# corresponding RuntimePermission ("defineClassInPackage."+package) has
# been granted.
#
# by default, no packages are restricted for definition, and none of
# the class loaders supplied with the JDK call checkPackageDefinition.
#
package.definition=sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,\
org.apache.jasper.,org.apache.naming.,org.apache.tomcat.

#
#
# List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "common"
# classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
# Path may be relative to the CATALINA_HOME or CATALINA_BASE path or absolute.
# If left as blank,the JVM system loader will be used as Catalina's "common"
# loader.
# Examples:
#     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
#     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
#                  repositories
#     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
#
# Note: Values are enclosed in double quotes ("...") in case either the
#       ${catalina.base} path or the ${catalina.home} path contains a comma.
#       Because double quotes are used for quoting, the double quote character
#       may not appear in a path.
common.loader="${catalina.base}/lib","${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar","${catalina.home}/lib","${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"

#
# List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "server"
# classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
# Path may be relative to the CATALINA_HOME or CATALINA_BASE path or absolute.
# If left as blank, the "common" loader will be used as Catalina's "server"
# loader.
# Examples:
#     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
#     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
#                  repositories
#     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
#
# Note: Values may be enclosed in double quotes ("...") in case either the
#       ${catalina.base} path or the ${catalina.home} path contains a comma.
#       Because double quotes are used for quoting, the double quote character
#       may not appear in a path.
server.loader=

#
# List of comma-separated paths defining the contents of the "shared"
# classloader. Prefixes should be used to define what is the repository type.
# Path may be relative to the CATALINA_BASE path or absolute. If left as blank,
# the "common" loader will be used as Catalina's "shared" loader.
# Examples:
#     "foo": Add this folder as a class repository
#     "foo/*.jar": Add all the JARs of the specified folder as class
#                  repositories
#     "foo/bar.jar": Add bar.jar as a class repository
# Please note that for single jars, e.g. bar.jar, you need the URL form
# starting with file:.
#
# Note: Values may be enclosed in double quotes ("...") in case either the
#       ${catalina.base} path or the ${catalina.home} path contains a comma.
#       Because double quotes are used for quoting, the double quote character
#       may not appear in a path.
shared.loader=

# Default list of JAR files that should not be scanned using the JarScanner
# functionality. This is typically used to scan JARs for configuration
# information. JARs that do not contain such information may be excluded from
# the scan to speed up the scanning process. This is the default list. JARs on
# this list are excluded from all scans. The list must be a comma separated list
# of JAR file names.
# The list of JARs to skip may be over-ridden at a Context level for individual
# scan types by configuring a JarScanner with a nested JarScanFilter.
# The JARs listed below include:
# - Tomcat Bootstrap JARs
# - Tomcat API JARs
# - Catalina JARs
# - Jasper JARs
# - Tomcat JARs
# - Common non-Tomcat JARs
# - Test JARs (JUnit, Cobertura and dependencies)
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip=\
annotations-api.jar,\
ant-junit*.jar,\
ant-launcher.jar,\
ant.jar,\
asm-*.jar,\
aspectj*.jar,\
bootstrap.jar,\
catalina-ant.jar,\
catalina-ha.jar,\
catalina-jmx-remote.jar,\
catalina-storeconfig.jar,\
catalina-tribes.jar,\
catalina-ws.jar,\
catalina.jar,\
cglib-*.jar,\
cobertura-*.jar,\
commons-beanutils*.jar,\
commons-codec*.jar,\
commons-collections*.jar,\
commons-daemon.jar,\
commons-dbcp*.jar,\
commons-digester*.jar,\
commons-fileupload*.jar,\
commons-httpclient*.jar,\
commons-io*.jar,\
commons-lang*.jar,\
commons-logging*.jar,\
commons-math*.jar,\
commons-pool*.jar,\
dom4j-*.jar,\
easymock-*.jar,\
ecj-*.jar,\
el-api.jar,\
geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,\
h2*.jar,\
hamcrest-*.jar,\
hibernate*.jar,\
httpclient*.jar,\
icu4j-*.jar,\
jasper-el.jar,\
jasper.jar,\
jaspic-api.jar,\
jaxb-*.jar,\
jaxen-*.jar,\
jdom-*.jar,\
jetty-*.jar,\
jmx-tools.jar,\
jmx.jar,\
jsp-api.jar,\
jstl.jar,\
jta*.jar,\
junit-*.jar,\
junit.jar,\
log4j*.jar,\
mail*.jar,\
objenesis-*.jar,\
oraclepki.jar,\
oro-*.jar,\
servlet-api-*.jar,\
servlet-api.jar,\
slf4j*.jar,\
taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,\
tagsoup-*.jar,\
tomcat-api.jar,\
tomcat-coyote.jar,\
tomcat-dbcp.jar,\
tomcat-i18n-*.jar,\
tomcat-jdbc.jar,\
tomcat-jni.jar,\
tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,\
tomcat-juli.jar,\
tomcat-util-scan.jar,\
tomcat-util.jar,\
tomcat-websocket.jar,\
tools.jar,\
websocket-api.jar,\
wsdl4j*.jar,\
xercesImpl.jar,\
xml-apis.jar,\
xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,\
xmlParserAPIs.jar,\
xom-*.jar

# Default list of JAR files that should be scanned that overrides the default
# jarsToSkip list above. This is typically used to include a specific JAR that
# has been excluded by a broad file name pattern in the jarsToSkip list.
# The list of JARs to scan may be over-ridden at a Context level for individual
# scan types by configuring a JarScanner with a nested JarScanFilter.
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan=\
log4j-taglib*.jar,\
log4j-web*.jar,\
log4javascript*.jar,\
slf4j-taglib*.jar

# String cache configuration.
tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled=true
#tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.char.enabled=true
#tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.trainThreshold=500000
#tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.cacheSize=5000

# This system property is deprecated. Use the relaxedPathChars relaxedQueryChars
# attributes of the Connector instead. These attributes permit a wider range of
# characters to be configured as valid.
# Allow for changes to HTTP request validation
# WARNING: Using this option may expose the server to CVE-2016-6816
#tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x with jakarta.\* package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217350/deploying-spring-5-x-on-tomcat-10-x-with-jakarta-package)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have used tomcat 9 and 8.5 also it is also showing errors

Comment: On Tomcat 9.0 and earlier, you should check in the logs (`catalina.<date>.log` and `localhost.<date>.log`) if the application started without errors.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have updated the post please refer to the last part of the post.

Comment: You must have changed one of the `*.loader` properties in the `catalina.properties` file, hence the error.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz So what should I do now ?

Comment: You can revert `catalina.properties` to the [default content](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/conf/catalina.properties) or add the modified content of this file to your question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I have added the catalina.properties file content in the question

Comment: My guess is that your `catalina.base` and `catalina.home` Java system properties contain incorrect paths. If you start Tomcat using `startup.bat/catalina.bat` these are taken from the `CATALINA_HOME/CATALINA_BASE` OS environment variables (or guessed if these are empty).