# Spring Boot Application does not start after Deployment (Docker Compose)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat, docker-compose, catalina

Hey folks I have a problem: I need to deploy a Spring Boot App with docker compose but after docker has deployed the contents of the Folder Spring Boot does not start to boot.
The thing is this has worked before but now it won't so I think it has something to do with my docker configuration. I can't really read something out of the log, please help me.

Here are the outputs of docker-compose logs:

```
root@h2916245:/home/carta# docker-compose up
Creating network "carta_default" with the default driver
Creating carta_cartadb_1 ... done
Creating carta_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to carta_cartadb_1, carta_frontend_1
cartadb_1   | ********************************************************************************
cartadb_1   | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will allow
cartadb_1   |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your database without
cartadb_1   |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
cartadb_1   |          documentation about "trust":
cartadb_1   |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
cartadb_1   |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any other
cartadb_1   |          container on the same system.
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust. Replace
cartadb_1   |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a password in
cartadb_1   |          "docker run".
cartadb_1   | ********************************************************************************
cartadb_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
cartadb_1   | This user must also own the server process.
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
cartadb_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
cartadb_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
cartadb_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
cartadb_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
cartadb_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
cartadb_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
cartadb_1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
cartadb_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
cartadb_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
frontend_1  | NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
cartadb_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
cartadb_1   | syncing data to disk ... initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
cartadb_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
cartadb_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
cartadb_1   | ok
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | waiting for server to start....2021-10-06 18:18:23.390 UTC [50] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.390 UTC [50] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.394 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-06 18:18:23 UTC
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.401 UTC [50] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
cartadb_1   |  done
cartadb_1   | server started
cartadb_1   | CREATE DATABASE
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.735 UTC [50] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.735 UTC [50] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
cartadb_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2021-10-06 18:18:23.740 UTC [50] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 57) exited with exit code 1
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.740 UTC [52] LOG:  shutting down
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.756 UTC [50] LOG:  database system is shut down
cartadb_1   |  done
cartadb_1   | server stopped
cartadb_1   |
cartadb_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
cartadb_1   |
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.846 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.11
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.886 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.887 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.888 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.888 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.891 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-10-06 18:18:23 UTC
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.890 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 6 2021 16:22:12 UTC
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.11.0
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.0
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.891 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk-11
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.12+7
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.892 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.893 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.893 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
cartadb_1   | 2021-10-06 18:18:23.899 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.915 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.921 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.921 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.922 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.922 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.922 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.923 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.924 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.942 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.943 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:23.956 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:24.736 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:24.812 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1629] milliseconds
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:24.949 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:24.950 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.11]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:24.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/carta-1.3.war]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:25.555 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/carta-1.3.war] has finished in [591] ms
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:25.560 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
frontend_1  | 06-Oct-2021 20:18:25.587 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [765] milliseconds
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  cartadb:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=carta
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - cartadb
    image: tomcat
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    volumes:
            - ./carta-1.3.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/carta-1.3.war
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=carta
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

and here is my Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CartaApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CartaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please post the logs of the errors in the Spring console ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x with jakarta.\* package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217350/deploying-spring-5-x-on-tomcat-10-x-with-jakarta-package)

Comment: A Spring 5.x app will not work on Tomcat 10.x.

Comment: @HoseinIT That's the thing. Spring does not a thing so I have no output. The Spring initialization just wont start

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you but that wasn't the problem. I tried using tomcat 9.0 and nothing changed