# Deployment of a War file in Tomcat 10

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, server

I have created a simple java application using spring boot. Then created a war file. Then deployed in the local tomcat 10. Everything runs fine.
But when I deployed it in the tomcat of the production server(using Tomcat Web Application Manager), I gets a 404 error. If I go to the defined context path, I get

> "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Have I missed anything?

Comment: Have you looked at the tomcat logs when you deployed?

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186315/tomcat-404-error-the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-th

Comment: @tgdavies  found this log in "log/catalina.out" path
1. "org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat10/webapps/ABC.war]"
2. " org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of J.... Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
"
3. " org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat10/webapps/ABC.war] has finished in [1,596] ms"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x with jakarta.\* package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217350/deploying-spring-5-x-on-tomcat-10-x-with-jakarta-package)

Comment: You can deploy your WAR file to `webapps-javaee` so that Tomcat automatically converts it to Jakarta EE 9.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your war to a local tomcat server, it deploys your application with your application name.

Try:

```
http://localhost:port/your_app_name/dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

For older built war, you need to deploy it to directory

> webapps-javaee

(create a new directory if it doesn't exist) instead of

> webapps

.

[Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Specification_APIs)