# Spring MVC - Getting 404 error and not able to configure Dispatcher Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and trying to create my first project in Spring MVC. Please help me to resolve the following error: -

Getting following error in console: -

```
Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcher]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
```

Browser showing 404 error for the URL - http://localhost:9492/MvcProject/home
[image]

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <!-- Configure Dispatcher Servlet -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>    <!-- handles all requests starting with '/' -->
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="mvc.controller"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" name="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Controller Class**

```
package mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("This is home page");
        return "index1";
    }
}
```

**index1.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is our home page - index1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Eclipse Project hierarchy**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add javax.servlet-api.jar to your WEB-INF/lib directory. Maybe it is not in tomcat's lib folder. To download the jar go to

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You have to add javax.servlet-api dependency in the pom.xml file. After adding, apply Maven update and it will download the jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcher]
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet

Means your application is trying to use the class **`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`** but it can't find in your POJO. You have to add **[`HttpServlet`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/4.0.1)** dependency in your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I tried to add javax serlvet dependency, but it didn't work with Tomcat 10 as it switched from javax to jakarta package. Then I further researched and got to know Spring MVC doesn't have compatibility with Tomcat 10 as it stills depends on javax. Please read the following for more detail: -
[Deploying Spring 5.x on Tomcat 10.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217350/deploying-spring-5-x-on-tomcat-10-x)

Comment: use `tomcat 9`.